# Key/Value distributed database for caching binary data

Tags: nosql, key-value-store, aerospike

I am looking for distributed kv database for caching small binary objects, like images with TTL. Size limitation is not a problem, as I am planning to split each object anyway, to minimize latency. I need C# and Java drivers, and in very near future I will also need C++ driver. The databases like CouchDb and Redis seems to be document based. Mongo supports binary data and well documented, but it is persistent and I am not sure it is scalable in terms of throughput , Cassandra is also persistent and I am not sure about C++/C# drivers quality + need for constantly repair because of deletions.

Aerospike is commercial and also document based. Maybe Riak with memory or leveldb backend (anyone worked with its C++ client?)

Comment: Redis is not really document based, it has support for rich data types though.

Comment: Aerospike is not document based. It supports a blob datatype for storing binary data. It has Java/C#/C drivers.

Answer (score 4):

[Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/) would be a perfect solution for you because of below reasons:

**Serves all your Use cases**

1. Key Value based.
2. Open sourced from 3.0 version. Earlier upto 2 node Aerospike cluster was open sourced and 3 or more nodes cluster was paid.
3. Can be used in Caching mode with no persistence.
4. Supports LRU and TTL.
5. Can save binary data.

**Reasons for choosing Aerospike**

1. **Throughput**: Better than Mongo/Couchbase or any other NoSQL solution. See this http://www.aerospike.com/benchmark/.
   Have personally seen it work fine with more than 300k read TPS and 100k Write TPS concurrently.
2. Automatic and efficient data sharding, data re-balancing and data distribution using RIPEMD160.
3. Highly Available system in case of Failover and/or Network Partitions.

Answer (score 2):

[Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) (not CouchDB) is a great option for you. Highly scalable, easy to understand, use and scale. It's a KV document database evolved from memcached that also offers secondary indexes through Map/Reduce and many new things coming soon. You can still use memcached protocol/libraries or speed it up with Couchbase SDK's.

Comment: But isn't it significant overhead to store binary data as documents, in terms of capacity and network?

Comment: Couchbase allows you to store any type of values, you can store binary content, string, ... or JSON document. The only limitation is the size that is 20Mb. Couchbase is a Key Value and a Document database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Pivotal GemFire](http://www.gopivotal.com/pivotal-products/pivotal-data-fabric/pivotal-gemfire) Pivotal GemFire is a distributed data management platform providing dynamic scalability, high performance, and database-like persistence.

Pivotal GemFire also has client drivers in C++, C# and Java